# How to identiy that how many instances of Oracle are installed on linux environment

Tags: linux, command-line, installation

Last day, i was at one training for oracle installation and service start & shutdown. There i came to know about some linux commands to start and shutdown oracle instance on linux machine.

**To identify the instance running** : Below command will return all oracle instances which are currently running on that machine.

```
ps -ef |grep pmon
```

This command returns following results:

```
oracle    823     1  0 Dec03 ?        00:00:17 ora_pmon_instance1
oracle  19632     1  0 Nov17 ?        00:06:35 ora_pmon_instance2
oracle  24199     1  0 Nov20 ?        00:05:23 ora_pmon_instance3
```

Where `instance1`, `instance2` and `instance3` are 3 installations of oracle on linux, which are currently running.

**My query :** So, `ps -ef` will only show processes currently running for current user. Suppose, `instance3` is down and you need to start that instance. But, you don't know how many oracle instances are there on machine.

How would you got to know, that this instance is down?

In windows, there is way called services, where you could came to know that these installation are done on windows for oracle.

Comment: No, `-e` shows you processes for all users.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/oratab should provide this info

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_linux_oratab.htm

> The oratab file contains entries in the form of
>   ORACLE_SID:ORACLE_HOME:Y, the last character being a Y or N indicating
>   if the database should be started and stopped with the dbstart and
>   dbstop commands, respectively.  Here is a typical oratab entry:
>
> TEST:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1:Y
>
> Lines beginning with a pound sign (#) in the oratab file are comments.
>   Valid entries are typically found at the end of the oratab file.
>
> The oratab file can be edited manually using vi or another text
>   editor.  This is often necessary if you the ORACLE_HOMEof a database
>   should be changed.
>
> WARNING:  Never set ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_BASE variables manually.
>
> Under certain circumstances, it is useful to add an entry to the
>   oratab file that does not refer to a database.  This can allow setting
>   the necessary variables for Oracle without having a database
>   associated with the session.  To do that, follow the format mentioned
>   above to add an entry, making sure to set the last character to N so
>   the dbstart/stop commands do not attempt to start a database that is
>   not there.  This script shows an oratab entry not associated with a
>   database.
>
> 11g_db1:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1:N
>
> A dummy oratab entry like this can be useful on a system that does not
>   yet have a database configured on it or on an Oracle Application
>   Server or a Client install where there may never be a database.